# How to find eweekend date in excel?

Tags: excel, weekend

How to write a formula in excel which tells whether a date is a week end date or not. I am trying to get to a formula which takes date into consideration and tells me if the date is a Friday, add 2 days, else add 1 day

Comment: Show us what you already tried, and what is not working. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weekday function will do the job

Answer (score 1):

Weekday() returns a number for the day of the week, from 1 to 7. By default, 1 is Sunday, but parameters can make 1 refer to Monday or another weekday.

If you want to work with differences in days, also look at Networkdays() which returns the difference in days between two dates, not counting weekends and not counting a list of holiday dates you can specify.

Comment: Not to mention the [NETWORKDAYS.INTL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/NETWORKDAYS-INTL-function-A9B26239-4F20-46A1-9AB8-4E925BFD5E28), [WORKDAY](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WORKDAY-function-F764A5B7-05FC-4494-9486-60D494EFBF33) and [WORKDAY.INTL](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WORKDAY-INTL-function-A378391C-9BA7-4678-8A39-39611A9BF81D)  functions.

Comment: Yup. For stage II.